# Error about CreateDialog

Tags: dialog-window

Writing:

```
CreateDialog[{TextCell["Enter number: "], 
              InputField[Dynamic[nm], Number], 
              DefaultButton[DialogReturn[ret = nm]]}];

ConstantArray[0, nm];
```

I get:

> ConstantArray::ilsmn: Single or list of non-negative machine-sized integers expected at position 2 of ConstantArray[0,1].

and I do not know how to correct. Some idea? Thank you!

Comment: use `ConstantArray[0, ToExpression@nm]` or modify your `InputField[...]` to `InputField[Dynamic[nm], Number]`?

Comment: Then you have some odd cached definition. As you have it it works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example the `ConstantArray[0, nm]` is evaluated immediately after the creation of the dialog window, i.e. before you enter any input. What you need to do is have evaluations "pause" until you enter a number into the input window and the dialog closes. `DialogInput` is your friend.

```
DialogInput[
  DialogNotebook[{TextCell["Enter number: "], 
    InputField[Dynamic[nm], Number], 
    DefaultButton[DialogReturn[nm]]}]];

ConstantArray[0, nm]
```

While the above will "work" you need to add some checks of the input:

```
If[IntegerQ[nm],
 ConstantArray[0, nm],
 Print["Hey you need to enter an integer"]
 ]
```

[image]